# Is is possible to change the signature algorithm from SHA1 to SHA256 in Websphere Application Server V7.0.0.17?

Tags: certificate, websphere

I would like to know whether it is possible to change the signature algorithm from SHA1 to SHA256 in Websphere Application Server V7.0.0.17. ? If yes, is there any link which explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. If you procured your certificates from a CA other than the one built into WAS, procure new ones. If you let WAS manage your PKI, follow the instructions here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21959568

> To convert these certificates with the Administrative console click
>   Security > SSL certificate and key management > Manage FIPS. Then
>   click Convert Certificates

Comment: What about the certificates which are in built into WAS ? My requirement is to change all certificates from SHA1 to SHA256 in WAS 7.0.0.17.

And in WAS console, I don't have any option like "Manage FIPS" as mentioned above.